# The heel of Moshiach?

Tags: history, parts-of-the-body, messiah, arizal

I have seen quotes from various rabbis, the oldest dating back to the Ari Z"L that state that we are in the ikve d'Moshiach (the heels of the Messiah). Ostensibly that was meant to convey that Moshiach was coming soon. However, that doesn't seem to be the case.

This leads me to two possibilities either A)all those Rabbis were wrong or B)that term doesn't mean what I thought it meant.

Assuming we go with B) are there other possible meaning to the ikvei d'Moshiach?

Comment: Who determines what soon is?

Comment: @HachamGabriel well then the term has no meaning.

Comment: 500 years out of 5000 is soon.

Comment: maybe i should edit this into the question but often the comment is 'our generation is the ikvei moshiach'

Comment: @not-vram, yeah, maybe you should. Also, how do you know "that doesn't seem to be the case"? (Or do you mean "that doesn't seem to have been the case when the term was used, at least not until this generation" or something?)

Comment: apparently the chafetz chaim predicted there would be 3 stages in this period b4 moshiach comes. heard this many times, here's one version http://www.theyeshivaworld.com/coffeeroom/topic/the-chofetz-chaim-speaks-about-the-horrors-of-world-war-iii

Comment: Maybe they mean their generation could be ikvisa demishicha if they act properly

Comment: @Shmuel many rabbis gave exact dates which proved false.

Comment: Maybe it can be understood as "We are like Yaakov to the Moshiach."  What does that mean?  I am not sure.  Maybe, "We need to be wily to attain it"?

Comment: I mean the previous comment along the same midrashic lines as understanding that Ishmael mitzachek means "Ishmael was pretending to be Yitzhak"

Comment: @ShmuelBrin They didn't make their prediction 5000 years ago...

Comment: @DoubleAA It seems strange to speak about "rabbis" who make "predictions"  about the coming of Moshiach when doing so flies in the face of acceptable Mesorah and Daniel 12. Their predictions ipso facto discredit their predictions.

Answer (score 1):

Before World War Two, Rav Elchonon Wasserman wrote an entire sefer titled Ikvesa D'Meshicha which you may find particularly helpful in developing a clearer picture of the definition of the 'footsteps of Mashiach'. Some of the primary points he makes [include](https://www.etzion.org.il/en/lecture-02-holocaust) the rapid acceleration of global changes due to the relatively short time left in the master plan before the clock strikes 6000. Imagine that in the last century alone we had two seismic wars, Klal Yisroel regains Israel, the fall of communism, dizzying pace of technological advances in massive industries (food, medicine, digital, etc.), whatever the global effects Covid-19 will have on the broader world stage in so many ways - apparently, things were never this big this fast.

> The changes that take place in the world today within a short time,
> used to take hundreds of years.  We see that the wheel of time is
> spinning at lightning speed.  "What has God done to us?" ([Yirmiyahu
> 5:19](https://www.sefaria.org/Jeremiah.5.19?lang=bi)); why are conditions changing in this way? Concerning these
> questions, the Chafetz Chaim taught: Since the time of Creation and
> until today, endless accounts have piled up.  Before the Messiah
> comes, these accounts must be settled, because the redemption will
> remove the evil inclination, and thus all matters of this world that
> pertain to the battle waged against the evil inclination will be
> cancelled.  Therefore, every person must settle whatever debt he still
> owes God.  Since the time of the Messiah is very close, it is
> imperative that this process be speeded up.  From the day that the
> Chafetz Chaim, z"l, expressed this view, the pace of events in the
> world has grown even faster.  Overnight, literally, things have
> happened that previously would have taken many generations… It is as
> though the wheel of time is accelerating under pressure from an
> external command: "Hurry up!"  Anyone with intelligence can understand
> that we are living in a special period, which is destined to change
> the entire world order; day by day, the pace grows faster…